# A slash at the end of routes in ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

Is it possible to add a slash at the end of all routes in ng-admin. For example, `http://localhost/api/v1/users/` instead of `http://localhost/api/v1/users`
I use the [getting started](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/Getting-started.md) ng-admin application

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a trailing `/` at the URL, you need to provide an extra `/` in your [router file](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/src/javascripts/ng-admin/Crud/routing.js#L357) where you specify `url` for each state.
e.g: 
Instead of

`url: '/:entity/delete/:id',`
you need to write `url: '/:entity/delete/:id/',`

Notice the trailing `/`.
This configuration will handle the URLs in your app.

Comment: I don't have a router file and I can't override standard ng-admin routers. ng-admin sends request to wrong URL for getting list of users and I don't know how to change this URL

Comment: any solution on this?